# Getting Xcode App Delegates Error because of IBOutlets despite seemingly a correct connection

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

getting this error:

Thread 1: "[<UIViewController 0x7fdca0609970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key billTextField."

The build succeeds, but cannot run it.

I have already checked the connections inspector and deleted the connection. The build runs successfully when I do that, but it defeats the point because I need to establish this IBoutlet. When I try to re-establish the connection, the circle next to the IB outlet is filled in and there are no exclamation marks next to the circle when looking at the connections inspector. I did not rename the file mistakenly and there are no missing connections

(I attached a screenshot in case I missed something). The outlets you see that are not connected are because I deleted their connections.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of4wk.png)

I'm following Angela Yu's tutorial and have literally copied her exact files. Her completed example of the project runs fine, but for some reason mine does not the minute I make IBoutlet connections. I've also tried deleting and re-doing the project, restarting Xcode and deleting derived data. At a loss for what else could be causing this issue.

Comment: I run into this issue sometimes with Xamarin.iOS, best solution without opening the nib file as source code and see what still has references to it (which you can still do). Is delete the textField from the nib and remove the outlet > Clean > build > Add the UI back in fresh (don't undo the delete) > then name the outlet something else > then finally run

Comment: would I even have a nib file if I'm using storyboard?

Comment: Do the same process but in the storyboard: so 'delete the textField from the nib' to 'delete the textField from the viewController within your storyboard'.